# Rails auto_complete "undefined method `auto_complete_for'" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, autocomplete

rails -> 2.3.8
ruby -> 1.8.7

After auto_complete plugin installstion i still have "undefined method `auto_complete_for'" problem!

Andrey-Bezruks-MacBook-Pro:eyeonasia.stage wizeflux$ ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/rails/auto_complete.git --force
svn: '/Users/wizeflux/Projects/ionasia/eyeonasia.stage/vendor/plugins' is not a working copy
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/wizeflux/Projects/ionasia/eyeonasia.stage/vendor/plugins/auto_complete/.git/
warning: Option "depth" is ignored for github.com/rails/auto_complete.git

From github.com/rails/auto_complete
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Andrey-Bezruks-MacBook-Pro:eyeonasia.stage wizeflux$

after restarting server i get an error on line " auto_complete_for :listings, :name " -> undefined method `auto_complete_for' for #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the git: address, also try it without the extra --force and svn option, see if they are causing the issue.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/auto_complete.git
```